# Values not displaying in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Please help me to Display the parsed json value from an external json file. i am trying to parse external JSON file in javescript and trying to display it in html. but json file is not parsing. please help out.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>$SiteName: Details </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2   /jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="http://www.json.org/json2.js"></script>
<script>

function test() {

var people = [];
$.getJSON('result_data.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data.result, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + i.FName + "</td>" +
       "<td>" + i.LName + "</td>" + "<td>" + i.Email + "</td>" + "<td>" + i.telno + "</td>" + "<td>" + i.msg + "</td>" + "</tr>"
       $('#userdata tbody').append(tblRow);
 });

});

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="test();">

<div class = "wrapper">
<div class = "profile">
<h3> User feedback </h3>
<hr color = "orange"/>
<table id = "userdata" border="2">
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>telno</th>
        <th>msg</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

result_data.json is :

```
{
    "result": {
        "Email": "xyz@gmail.com",
        "FName": "Harry",
        "Gender": "male",
        "LName": "potter",
        "_id": "535b69928844610ff591be50",
        "msg": "hello",
        "telno": "4567891230"
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact contents of a call to `results_data.json`.

Answer (score 1):

In the callback for `$.each`, the first argument is the key or index, so `i.Email` won't work. The second argument is the value, and you can also use `this` to access the value.

Use `data.result[i].Email` or `f.Email` or simply `this.Email`.

```
var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + this.FName + "</td>" +
```